# Calling a Stateful bean action that returns a JSF view Id in a loop to render PDFs

Tags: javascript, html, jsf, seam2

Is there a way to call a Stateful Bean action that renders a PDF using JSF more than once (in a loop)? I tried doing it via Javascript where I invoke a .click() event on each button I created for each PDF job I'd like to render. The xhtml looks like the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:s="http://jboss.com/products/seam/taglib"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:a="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">

<ui:composition>    
    <div id="dataSizingDivGrowth">
            <f:subview id="fbiAdminId" rendered="#{user.FBIAdmin}">
                <h:inputHidden value="#{pdfPrinter.emailsSize}" id="emailSizeId"/>
                <h:inputHidden value="#{pdfPrinter.downloadIds}" id="downloadIds"/>             
                <br />
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="4" align="center">
                            <button type="button" onclick="savePDF();">Send Emails</button>
                            <c:forEach items="#{pdfPrinter.downloadIdsArr}" var="value">                                
                                <h:form id="emailAutoForm-#{value}" target="_blank">
                                    <h:inputHidden value="#{pdfPrinter.currDownloadId}" id="currDownloadId-#{value}"/>
                                    <h:commandButton action="#{pdfPrinter.emailAutoCD()}" id="savePDFId-#{value}" style="display:none"/>
                                </h:form>
                            </c:forEach>                                                                                                                                
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </f:subview>            

    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">     
        function savePDF() {
            //alert("start saving pdf");
            var emailSize = document.getElementById("emailAuto:fbiAdminId:emailSizeId").value;
            alert("before downloadIdsArr " + emailSize);
            var downloadIds = document.getElementById("emailAuto:fbiAdminId:downloadIds").value;
            var downloadIdsArr = downloadIds.split("?");
            //alert("before getting length");
            //alert(downloadIds);
            //alert(downloadIdsArr.length);
            //alert(downloadIdsArr[0]);

            for ( var i = 0; i &lt; emailSize; i++ ) {
                var j = function(x) {
                    document.getElementById("emailAuto:fbiAdminId:emailAutoForm-" + downloadIdsArr[x] + ":currDownloadId-" + downloadIdsArr[x]).value = downloadIdsArr[x];                              
                    document.getElementById("emailAuto:fbiAdminId:emailAutoForm-" + downloadIdsArr[x] + ":savePDFId-" + downloadIdsArr[x]).click();                 
                }
            j(i);
            }
        }
    </script>
</ui:composition>
</html>
```

What happens is that the javascript loop only calls the last iteration and executes that and ignores anything before. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's the reason you want to get in invoked in a loop? That's going to result in appalling user experience. If you want the user to download more than one file at once, wrap them in a zip at server side and make a single request.

Comment: My goal is to have multiple users request reports in PDF formats. What I'm trying to achieve is to get every single user and loop through them one by one to generate the PDF and then save it a in location on the server. Unfortunately, the current architecture is not making it easy for me, so I'm trying to use JSF and RenderFilter in order to do my task.

Comment: I  think you shouldn't go with stateful, nor performing any loop. When an end user makes a request, just generate the PDF and store it in the path you choose in the server. You'll be able to grab all the pdfs whenever you want.

Comment: Unfortunately, the request is not made by the user, it's made by an admin. The reason why it's because we are sending reports based on Quarter Time data and we will send out those reports once every quarter.

Comment: Well, so you should have written it in your post. Anyway, I don't see the stateful requirement anywhere, neither I understand why you are managing it at javascript side. Just provide one entry point in your server which takes the users you want to process the report for and do the work. Then, if you want them to be sent at every quarter, just use a scheduled cronjob.

Comment: To generate a single PDF, we use JSF. For example, if there is a home.xhtml page on the page that we would like to render it as a PDF, we have a PDF version of it which would be called homePDF.xhtml and send it to a PDFPrintingBean

Comment: To generate a single PDF, we use JSF. For example, if there is a home.xhtml page on the page that we would like to render it as a PDF, we have a PDF version of it which would be called homePDF.xhtml and send it to a PDFPrintingBean

Name("pdfPrinter")
Stateful
Clustered
Scope(ScopeType.CONVERSATION)
SerializedConcurrentAccess

The architecture of generating the PDF is using JSF to return a viewID which would be homePDF.xhtml which then gets rendered by a RenderFilter. It's a very confusing process, but it works and honestly I'm trying to work with it instead of rewriting it.

Comment: I know it's not clean and not good performance wise, but as I mentioned, it's going to be run by an admin. So, that's why I'm trying to submit multiple times using Javascript, but the loop only executes the last PDF and doesn't do it once at a time.